# Androidx FragmentStatePagerAdapter - Cannot setMaxLifecycle for Fragment not attached to FragmentManager

Tags: android-viewpager, androidx, fragmentstatepageradapter

`Viewpager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in `androidx`. When I try to replace a fragment on selected position (say pos 0) I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot setMaxLifecycle for Fragment not attached to FragmentManager`

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is constructed in following way:

```
private inner class Adapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {...}
```

Before migrating to `androidx` it was constructed as:

`private inner class Adapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {...}` and everything worked fine.

With `androidx` this way works OK as well but this constructor is now deprecated in `androidx`.

I replace fragment using a method in adapter which triggers `notifyDataSetChanged()` then method

```
override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int { .. }
```

on some conditions returns POSITION_NONE and subsequently

`override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment { ... }` creates and returns new fragment to replace the old one. However I got the above mentioned exception.

I do not show code because implementation of above methods in adapter seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: Problem I described concerned androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01. Now actual is androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0 and seems like everything is ok